USB breakout board for turning off device - SHIELD help needed
Currently I design a breakout board which I plan to introduce between USB device (e.g. keyboard) and USB host (e.g. computer). For reference take a look at picture below.

On breakout board there is circuitry to enable turning VBUS off on USB device's side. That way I can turn power on/off on USB device which is crucial for my application.
I designed circuitry and tested that it works. Now I would like to add USB connectors on each side of the breakout board and interconnect everything.
I attach schematic as PDF. Please take a look at it before you comment. It can be found here PDF schematic
I have unclear points regarding shield connection.
Please take into consideration that I do NOT have any outer metal enclosure for whole device so I cannot connect shield to it.
My questions:

Should I interconnect 2 shields of each connector or should I leave them unconnected? Connecting them would interconnect 2 shields of 2 different USB cables?
Should I connect shield at one side of the breakout board to GND? I want to avoid creating ground loops?
Is it good idea to have signals on TOP layer, GND on plane in 2nd layer (with proper impedance control) and then GND_DRAIN connected in a single track?


Welcome! Please embed your schematic as an image.


Yes you should. To the devices, it must look like there is a single cable in between with two connectors. Taking the cable as an example, you cannot take a cable and cut the shield in the middle and expect the cable to work.

This way you let both the devices to handle the shield how they want it to be handled. The host likely connects it to GND. The device does what it thinks is best for EMI and signal integrity.

No you should not, if you want to avoid ground loops. Let the devices decide if they want a ground loop or not like with a normal single cable.

Maybe, but do realize that you are unlikely to be able to have impedance matching or sensible track geometry if you use only 2 layers or a special PCB.



Thank you for your input! To your comment in point 3 - I actually have 4 layer PCB with impedance matching, but I use only first two layers. That is because that way there is smaller diaelectric gap between TOP layer and LAYER2, so the track geometry can be sensible.
